# Writing a uint8 variable on two bytes?

Tags: c, embedded, bitwise-operators

So a bit of a weird one because I am working with an interface in which I do not have access. But the gist of it is this: I have an array of 16-bytes, 16 uint8 elements. The first 12 elements are quite specific, meaning for array[0] and array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5XvE.png) I personally give specific values, while the next 10 elements, I need to copy the elements of another array. The problem I have is with the last 4 elements of the array, basically the last 4 bytes. In my "diagram" I have something like this:
[image]

As you can see in the picture, it says that index and ID are not like arrays with 2 uint8 elements, it looks like they are a single variable that occupies 2 bytes each. The problem however is that to get the values for index and ID, I use the interface I was talking about earlier, and this interface accepts uint8* values. So I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Should I declare index and ID of type uint8 and pass them inside this function where they will get a certain value, but then use bitwise operators to place it on 2 bytes? My code implementation looks like this:

```
uint8 FinalArray[16];
uint8 index;
uint8 ID;
uint8 buffer[10];

FinalArray[1] = 0x01;
FinalArray[2] = 0x10;
//I do some data manipulation for buffer here, does not matter
memcpy(&FinalArray[2], buffer, sizeof(buffer));

//and here I am unsure of how I should proceed
Get_IndexAndID(&index, &ID);
//the function returns just 1 or 0 in case it was successful or not, so I guess I need to pass the variables by reference for them to change value inside the function itself
//I also got a hint that inside this function, both index and ID get values because they are the "destination" inside a memcpy function, but I am not sure if this changes the way they are passed or what

//is this even doing what I am thinking of?
FinalArray[12] = index & 0xFF;
FinalArray[13] = (index >> 8) & 0xFF;
FinalArray[14] = ID & 0xFF;
FinalArray[15] = (ID >> 8) & 0xFF;

Any help, additions or corrections to my code would be really welcome. Thanks!
```

Comment: You are most likely just fine doing `Get_IndexAndID(FinalArray + 12, FinalArray + 14);`. It's impossible to tell what exactly you need to do without having access to the code for `Get_IndexAndID()` or its documentation.

Comment: Yup, if the endianness of it works out, your bitwise work with & operator looks correct.  Another arguably easier way is to cast the array to type 16bit int, and then assign the last two ints of the array (offset 6 and 7) to the variable 16bit int.  If I'm not clear I'm happy to post code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli But "FinalArray + 12" isn't it equivalent to like the 4 element of FinalArray? Maybe I am getting it mixed up because I never call it the way you just did now.
In other words, are you saing I can do it like ````Get_IndexAndID(&FinalArray[12], &FinalArray[14])````. Something like this?

Comment: @gregspears Heh, I apologize, I am not 100% sure what you mean. I just recently switched to embedded type projects and working with bitwise operators is my new challenge at the moment. Just you saying that what I did with the final parts of my code is OK is making me happy, lol.

Comment: @Ciuboss -- Glad to hear that.    [Here is that other way](https://godbolt.org/z/qG6T4ajTq) I was describing -- cheers!

Comment: @gregspears Oh damn this is interesting, I've never seen it done like this. I will look over your solution to maybe understand some aspects a bit more. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ciuboss --  very welcome!  [Here is the same code with more notes in the comments](https://godbolt.org/z/5Tz3dG8MP).  I can appreciate that this is new territory for you.

Comment: @gregspears it is pointer punning and it invokes undefined behaviour as it violates strict aliasing rules. Do not advice people to do this. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a typo

```
FinalArray[1] = 0x01;
FinalArray[2] = 0x10;
```

as indexes start from `0` in C language.

You need to know the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) required by the interface.

```
void bigEndian(uint8_t *array, uint16_t val)
{
    array[0] = val >> 8;
    array[1] = val;    
}

void littleEndian(uint8_t *array, uint16_t val)
{
    array[1] = val >> 8;
    array[0] = val;    
}

uint8_t *formArray(uint8_t *array, const uint8_t *buffer, const uint16_t index, const uint16_t ID, int endianess)
{
    array[0] = 0x1;
    array[1] = 0x10;
    memcpy(array + 2, buffer, 10);
    if(endianess)
    {
        bigEndian(array + 12, index);
        bigEndian(array + 14, ID);
    }
    else
    {
        littleEndian(array + 12, index);
        littleEndian(array + 14, ID);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your diagram, it can be a `struct`:

```
struct diagram {
    uint8 v01;
    uint8 v10;
    uint8 buffer[10];
    uint16 index;
    uint16 ID;
};

union bigbuf {
    uint8 array[16];
    struct diagram diagram;
};
```

Based on your code for putting `index` and `ID` into your `FinalArray` (i.e. the `<<`), they are 16 bits each. So, they should be `uint16` and *not* `uint8`

---

C arrays are "origin 0" and *not* "origin 1". So, instead of:

```
FinalArray[1] = 0x01;
FinalArray[2] = 0x10;
```

You want:

```
FinalArray[0] = 0x01;
FinalArray[1] = 0x10;
```

---

Refactoring your code:

```
union bigbuf bigbuffer;
uint8 buffer[10];

struct diagram *dia = &bigbuffer.diagram;

dia->v01 = 0x01;
dia->v10 = 0x10;

// manipulate buffer ...

// copy buffer into struct ...
buffer[0] = 1;
memcpy(dia->buffer,buffer,10);

// get index and ID
Get_IndexANDID(&dia->index,&dia->ID);
```

Now things are fully filled in.

---

We can put all the data directly into the struct *without* extra copying:

```
union bigbuf bigbuffer;

struct diagram *dia = &bigbuffer.diagram;

dia->v01 = 0x01;
dia->v10 = 0x10;

// manipulate buffer directly ...
uint8 *buffer = dia->buffer;
buffer[0] = 1;

// get index and ID
Get_IndexANDID(&dia->index,&dia->ID);
```

---

Most systems these days are "little-endian", so the above code will [probably] work.

A limited number of systems [some still being used] are "big-endian".

So, if you're not sure, you can store the data in "network byte order", which is always "big-endian":

```
union bigbuf bigbuffer;

struct diagram *dia = &bigbuffer.diagram;

dia->v01 = 0x01;
dia->v10 = 0x10;

// manipulate buffer directly ...
uint8 *buffer = dia->buffer;
buffer[0] = 1;

// get index and ID
Get_IndexANDID(&dia->index,&dia->ID);

// convert to network byte order
dia->index = htons(dia->index);
dia->ID = htons(dia->ID);
```

When receiving such a "packet", we'd need to reverse this:

```
// receive packet from network ...

// convert to native/host byte order
dia->index = ntohs(dia->index);
dia->ID = ntohs(dia->ID);
```

Comment: It is only if endianness match

Comment: @0___________ Yes, I was going to get to that. But, with 2 close votes, I wanted to get the answer up before being closed out.

Comment: Not a good one. You assume no padding etc. This answer attempt requires much more work to be correct.

Comment: @0___________ Throwing that all in at once to a newbie can be confusing. A progression is better. But, specifically, here, there should not be any padding required since we're using types with explicit lengths. The struct aligns naturally on all arches that I'm aware of (even historically).

Comment: Simply it might not work at all. It is not throwing anything. The solution using union is simply incorrect.

Comment: @0___________ Using the `union` was a nicety to show the relationship between the struct and the flat byte array. But, _why_ wouldn't it work? I can just as easily have two globals and use `memcpy`

Comment: Because you assume **no padding** in the struct. Without compiler extensions there is no way to enforce it (like `__attribute__((packed))`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255920/discussion-between-craig-estey-and-0).

Comment: I do not wanty to DV

Comment: @0___________ I'm waiting for OP to comment on what s/he doesn't understand. Also, since the question wasn't a full MRE (e.g. no definition of some functions, context as to how the data is gotten, sent, received, etc.) it's difficult to provide a full code answer. But, rather than passively/incrementally mention that things are wrong (without explanation of what _you_ consider to be wrong (e.g.) you said union was wrong, but then had to be prompted for the `packed`) try being collaborative. _No_ padding is required and _none_ will occur because the native alignment on all arches is the same.

Comment: simply `sizeof(struct diagram)` is not guaranteed by the C standard to be 16. If you use it to form that array the code is invalid.

Comment: @CraigEstey although `sizeof(struct diagram) == 16` is likely true, some [unicorn](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215113/29485) platform may differ.  Consider a `static_assert(sizeof(struct diagram) == 16,  "Strange struct diagram"):` to at least _detect_ a troublesome platform.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica As I've mentioned in other posts, it's time to move out of the vacuum tube era. The struct _will_ match [at least] the first 16 bytes as _no_ arch will pad within it because of the natural alignment of `uint8` and `uint16`. We have `uint8 x; uint8 y; uint16 z;` and _not_ `uint8 x; uint16 z;` which would add a hidden pad byte. The unicorns don't apply here, for two reasons: We're only doing `short` and _not_ `int` and `char` is 8 bits (POSIX: `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Again, _no_ arch will pad at the end because the struct size is [at least] 16 and that's _more_ alignment than an intrinsic type (e.g. `double` at 8 bytes). So, no padding to align the struct [at the end]. And, it won't, but even if it did, the union makes this okay. Further, consider that OP is a _beginner_, so the [longwinded] technically correct with caveats for all computers ever created (real, imaginary, or theoretical), is way beyond what they need or want.